# Avoid instantiate object when every time constructor being called

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a `PersonViewModel` class and bind with Person User Control. Everytime when I select Person Use Control page, `createPersonCommand`, `deletePersonCommand`, `viewPersonCommand` will always reinstantiate. Are there any ideas to create those command once ? Execpt for `InitializePersonCollection` method because will retrieve latest date from DB.

My senior comments on my assignment, and he was mentioned on this.

```
    private ICommand createPersonCommand;

    public ICommand CreatePersonCommand
    {
        get { return createPersonCommand; }
    }

    private ICommand deletePersonCommand;

    public ICommand DeletePersonCommand
    {
        get { return deletePersonCommand; }
    }

    private ICommand viewPersonCommand;

    public ICommand ViewPersonCommand
    {
        get { return viewPersonCommand; }
    }

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        createPersonCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteCreatePersonCommand);
        deletePersonCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteDeletePersonCommand);
        viewPersonCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteViewPersonCommand);
        InitializePersonCollection();
    }
```

Comment: This question does not make any sense.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it? If at all you want to avoid, just remove that code. Or explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: You can make them static, but I don't think it is a big issue to create new DelegateCommand each time you select a Person (except if you are fast enough to select 1000000 persons per seconds).

Comment: Shouldn't that be the intended behavior? Assuming you instantiate a new ViewModel every time you open the screen, the associated commands should also be created, or wasn't that your question?

Comment: sorry guys for ambiguous, have updated question

Comment: Is the current approach creating any kind of problem?

Comment: Answer depends on what those methods does. Do they uses instance fields or methods. Can you post that code? I mean code for `ExecuteCreatePersonCommand`, `ExecuteDeletePersonCommand`, ...

Comment: You have *model* code in your *view model*. Your view and view model should not include any direct code which accesses external resources.

Comment: Code added. Current approach does not create any problem

Comment: *My senior comments on my assignment, and he was mentioned on this.* - You mean someone is telling you that this approach is bad? Could you add his comments on **why** it's a bad approach?

Comment: You are not really creating the same `DelegateCommand`s over and over again - you are creating `DelegateCommand`s for each `PersonViewModel` instance that are tied to this particular `PersonViewModel` instance. For example, `createPersonCommand` will run `ExecuteCreatePersonCommand` in the context of this particular `PersonViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the command executing methods are not `static`, you will need to do this. If for whatever reason you can make the command methods `static`, you could make your DelegateCommands `static` as well and only assign the static instances to your members.

But as people already mentioned, that would not make sense. The code you have is a well established pattern. There is no reason to change it.

Maybe you should check if the commands are actually well placed. Does every person need it's own command, or do you need commands in your main viewmodel that get a single person as parameter? That might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "lazy-loading". Then commands will be instantiated on-demand and will not affect speed of loading data from database.

```
private ICommand createPersonCommand;
public ICommand CreatePersonCommand
{
    get {
        if (createPersonCommand == null) {
            createPersonCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteCreatePersonCommand)
        }
        return createPersonCommand;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which in a WPF application is pretty pointless, because they are being accessed when the XAML is being created.

Comment: @Default So, if you have virtualized list, the property is not accessed until is accessed from UI component (propably by binding).